# The Universal Language

Tags: cipher, visual

*Or should I say, a CoSmOs CrYPt?*

This was found inscribed in a rock in the middle of the desert. Perhaps the ancients knew more about the sciences than we thought they did - after all, this puzzle uses a kind of 'universal language'.

It's not simply enough to fill the grid, you see. But one's absence may lead you to a solution.

[image: CIDOIREP]

***Can you find the single word solution?***

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> As *CoSmOs CrYPt* suggests, we are dealing with [periodic table elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table) (what's more universal as a language than atoms?).
>
>  We can fill the grid with the english names of such elements (Paint was definitely a bad choice):
>
>   [image]
>
>  As we can see some elements are missing, the red ones, namely `Phosphorus, Arsenic, Selenium, Rubidium, Yttrium.`
>
>  Their symbols are `P, As, Se, Rb, Y`, which reveal the word [`Passer-by`](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/passer-by).
>
>  Is this a message left from a visiting alien civilization which was just a 'passer-by' in our world?

Comment: Funny how they left a message in a language that was not yet developed, using words that did not exist.

Comment: @Kami Or maybe they are exactly who created the language itself... zan-zan-ZAAAAN!

Comment: Illuminati confirmed